# Executing pre-build-up array with PDO Execute

Tags: php, arrays, database, function, pdo

I am trying to pass through any query to a function using PDO. 
I have build up the array through a loop function and try to insert it into the execute(array(....)) function, but it's not getting through.

FUNCTION CODE

```
    public function ShowData($sql,$variable)
{
    $execute_string = "";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($variable);
    echo "</pre>";
    $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($variable); $i++)
    {
        if($i != 0) $execute_string .= ",";
        $placeholder = $i + 1;
        $execute_string .= "':$placeholder' => '".$variable[$i]."'";
    } 
    echo $sql."<br>";
    echo $execute_string;
    $q->execute(array($execute_string));
    echo "<br>Execute Succeeded";
    return $row = $q->fetchAll();
}
```

VIEWPAGE CODE

```
$author = "Nemoza";
$name = "MBICO_mailer";
$project = $data->ShowData("SELECT * FROM mbico_projects WHERE author=:1 AND name=:2", array($author,$name));
```

OUTPUT FROM FUNCTION W/ DEBUGGING

```
Array
(
    [0] => Nemoza
    [1] => MBICO_mailer
)
SELECT * FROM mbico_projects WHERE author=:1 AND name=:2
':1' => 'Nemoza',':2' => 'MBICO_mailer'
```

However, the 'Execute Succeeded' text is not being printed, and the execute(array...)) is not actually executing.

What am I doing wrong, and how else should I do it?

Comment: Did you try the request independently ? I'm just guessing because I never tried, but, using ':1' is maybe not considered as a string, try ':var1' instead.

Comment: :1 and :var1 both work the same way. :1 works fine if I enter it 'hardcoded' into the execute. When changing it to :var1 it makes no difference.

Comment: execute() takes an array as parameter, not a string

Comment: So how do I get around that so that my function will still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an example you can use:

```
public function ShowData($sql,$variable) {
    $bind = [];
    foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
        $ph = $key+1;
        $bind[":" . $ph] = $value;
    }
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($bind);

    return $stmt->fetchAll();

}
```

it's used like this:

```
$sql = 'select * from users where username = :1 or username = :2';
$bind = ['123', '456'];
$db->ShowData($sql, $bind);
```

as mentioned in the comments to your question, you need to send an array to execute() function, and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it like this:

```
public function ShowData($sql,$variable)
{
    $execute_string = array();
    $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    foreach($variable as $item) 
    {
        $execute_string[] = $item;
    }
    $q->execute($execute_string);
    return $q->fetchAll();
}

$project = $data->ShowData("SELECT * FROM mbico_projects WHERE author=? AND title=?", array($author, $title));
```